# I want give options to admin to add an href link from a form's input

Tags: php, laravel

I have an admin panel which has a lot of input fields. The admins who will ultimately use this admin panel don't know how to code.  They want to write some text + words referring to a link (an href). They could write several lines of text linking to a url within the same input field on their admin panel.

For example:
[`exampleofawebsite.com/website`]

in the input field, so the output will show:

```
<a href"exampleofawebsite.com">website</a>
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement this using PHP/Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks a case for two way binding, so why don't use Vue?

```js
new Vue({

 el: '#app',
  
  data:  {
  
   inputText: 'https://www.google.com'
    
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <h3>My site</h3>
  
    <input type="text" v-model="inputText">  >>> <a :href="inputText"> My link </a>
  
</div>
```